# case statement, THEN clause error

Tags: sql, cognos

```
CASE 
WHEN ([PPM 360 View].[Project Data Lite].[Last Review Date] between add_months(trunc (current_date),-6) and current_date) 
    THEN 'Reviewed Within Last 6 Months'
WHEN ([PPM 360 View].[Project Data Lite].[Last Review Date] between add_months(trunc (current_date),-6)-1 and add_months(trunc (current_date),-12)) 
    THEN '7-12 Months Past Due'
WHEN ([PPM 360 View].[Project Data Lite].[Last Review Date] < add_months(trunc (current_date),-12)) 
    THEN 'More Than 12 Months Past Due'
WHEN ([PPM 360 View].[Project Data Lite].[Last Review Date] is null) 
    THEN 'Not Reviewed'
END
```

.... The 3rd THEN Statement that contains `'7-12 Months Past Due'`, will not correctly appear in the legend of the stacked bar chart I'm creating or populated in the column in the respective list. Any ideas why?

I've placed the same text in the `ELSE` statement and it appears but I'd rather not have to do that. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What version of SQL are you on? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: I'm working in cognos report studio

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a parentheses issue with the first add_months(), because you are subtracting 1 after and it isn't part of the calculation.  Is there a reason you aren't just subtracting 7 to begin with?